# User input looping and adding all inputs

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, loops, console-application

I needed to get the total of all the user's input products but I can't do it. I need to ask the user to choose the product and its quantity and then ask the user if she would like to add more products or pay it. The user will enter product again and its quantity. After it the program will ask again if add or pay. When the user choose pay it was supposed to output the total amount of products. Then lastly the program will ask the user if she/he would like to use the program again, if not, it'll exit.

```cs
int choice, quanti, decide, total, price;
string w = "WELCOME ";
Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - w.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);  // for setting string output on center top
Console.WriteLine(w);
Console.WriteLine("");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //time delay

string p = "HERE'S OUR MERCHANDISES! ";
Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - p.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);  // for setting string output on center top
Console.WriteLine(p);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//time delay

string[] products = { "[1]BLACKPINK Lightstick ", "[2]DREAMCATCHER Seasons Greetings", 
                        "[3]RED VELVET Summer Package"};

for (int g = 0; g < products.Length; g++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(products[g]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < products.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Pick your product: ");
    choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("BLACKPINK Lightstick 1500php");

            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("DREAMCATCHER Seasons Greetings 920php");

            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("RED VELVET Summer Package 980php");

            break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Quantity of product: ");
    quanti = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//time delay
    Console.WriteLine("[1] Add more products \t [2] Pay: ");
    decide = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (decide == 2)
    {
        decide++;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            price = 1500;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            price = 920;
        }

        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            price = 980;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        total = choice * price * quanti;
        Console.Write(total);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Pick your product: ");
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("BLACKPINK Lightstick 1500php");
                price = 1500;
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("DREAMCATCHER Seasons Greetings 920php");
                price = 920;
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("RED VELVET Summer Package 980php");
                price = 700;
                break;

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Quantity of product: ");
        quanti = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//time delay
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Add more products \t [2] Pay: ");
        decide = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (decide == 2)
        {
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                price = 1500;
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                price = 920;
            }
            else if (choice == 3)
            {
                price = 980;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            total = price * quanti;
            Console.Write(total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect and what is your program giving you?

Comment: I reformatted your code and removed three extraneous closing braces from the end.  When `decide == 2` it seems that `total = choice * price * quanti;` should be `total = price * quanti;` like when `decide != 2` since `choice` is the selected menu item.  Your second `for` loop should probably be a `while`/`do ... while` loop that prompts for products to add until the user opts to pay.

Answer (score 0):

check if this is what you expect.

```
int choice, quanti, decide, total, price;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            string w = "WELCOME ";
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - w.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);  // for setting string output on center top
            Console.WriteLine(w);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //time delay

            string p = "HERE'S OUR MERCHANDISES! ";
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - p.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);  // for setting string output on center top
            Console.WriteLine(p);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//time delay

            string[] products = { "[1]BLACKPINK Lightstick ", "[2]DREAMCATCHER Seasons Greetings",
                    "[3]RED VELVET Summer Package"};

            for (int g = 0; g < products.Length; g++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(products[g]);
            }

            Dictionary<int, int> ProductList = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            while (true)
            {
                {
                    Console.Write("Pick your product: ");
                    choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("BLACKPINK Lightstick 1500php");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("DREAMCATCHER Seasons Greetings 920php");

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("RED VELVET Summer Package 980php");

                            break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Quantity of product: ");
                    quanti = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (!ProductList.ContainsKey(choice))
                        ProductList.Add(choice, quanti);
                    else
                        ProductList[choice] += quanti;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//time delay
                    Console.WriteLine("[1] Add more products \t [2] Pay: ");
                    decide = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (decide == 2)
                        break;
                }
            }
            total = 0;
            foreach (int key in ProductList.Keys)
                switch (key)
                {
                    case 1:
                        total += ProductList[key] * 1500;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        total += ProductList[key] * 920;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        total += ProductList[key] * 980;
                        break;
                    default:
                        total += 0;
                        break;
                };
            Console.WriteLine("To Pay: " + total.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Another shopping? [1]Yes [2] No");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choice == 2)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir I've tried your answer and it works, I've just added a discount option. If it's not too much to ask for, I needed to output on the very last the receipt kind of thing, like it will output the users purchase, may I know how can I do this? I've tried outputting the variable that are used on acquiring users input but it only receipt the first product that the user purchased, it can't get the additional products that the user's get.

Comment: in the code, the list of products for the receipt is in the ProductList variable and the total value is in the total variable. Now is the question of how you'd like to calculate the discount. If you'd like to add the discount for some product you can do that in the loop where the total value is calculated if you like to add the discount to the total value you need to do this after the loop. But if you'd like the discount on the last receipt you need to declare additional variable for where you will store all client's receipts

Comment: Then I'll just need to output the ProductList so that I can output all of the users purchased products and it's total?

Comment: Can i output it like this sir? Purchased products - quantity - total - cash - change

Comment: check the next answer

Answer (score 0):

```
struct product
    {
        public string Name;
        public float Price;
        public float Discount;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        int choice, quanti, decide;
        float total;
        Dictionary<int,product> products=new Dictionary<int, product>();
        products.Add(1,new product() { Name = "BLACKPINK Lightstick", Price = 1500, Discount = 0 });
        products.Add(2, new product() { Name = "DREAMCATCHER Seasons Greetings", Price = 920, Discount = 0 });
        products.Add(3, new product() { Name = "RED VELVET Summer Package", Price = 980, Discount = 0 });
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            string w = "WELCOME ";
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - w.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);  // for setting string output on center top
            Console.WriteLine(w);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //time delay
            string p = "HERE'S OUR MERCHANDISES! ";
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - p.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);  // for setting string output on center top
            Console.WriteLine(p);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//time delay
            foreach (int key in products.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("["+key.ToString()+"]"+products[key].Name);
            }

            Dictionary<int, int> ProductList = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            while (true)
            {
                {
                    Console.Write("Pick your product: ");
                    choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine(products[choice].Name+" "+products[choice].Price.ToString()+"php");
                    Console.WriteLine("Quantity of product: ");
                    quanti = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (!ProductList.ContainsKey(choice))
                        ProductList.Add(choice, quanti);
                    else
                        ProductList[choice] += quanti;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//time delay
                    Console.WriteLine("[1] Add more products \t [2] Pay: ");
                    decide = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (decide == 2)
                        break;
                }
            }
            total = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            foreach (int key in ProductList.Keys)
            {
                total += products[key].Price*ProductList[key];
                Console.WriteLine(products[key].Name.PadRight(40,' ')+ProductList[key].ToString().PadLeft(3,' ')+ " * "+products[key].Price.ToString().PadLeft(10,' '));
                Console.WriteLine((products[key].Price * ProductList[key]).ToString().PadLeft(56, ' '));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(("To Pay: " + total.ToString()).PadLeft(56,' '));
            Console.WriteLine("Cash: ");
            var cash = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(("Change: " + (cash - total).ToString()).PadLeft(56, ' '));

            Console.WriteLine("Another shopping? [1]Yes [2] No");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choice == 2)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think a new answer is warranted when you can just [edit the existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70143780/edit) to meet any new requirements.  For both answers, just dumping a block of code with no explanation of what you've changed and why isn't very helpful.  See [Do good answers require an explanation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405939/150605)